# OpenCV error: No GPU support, cannot build with WITH_CUDA=ON

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to make OpenCV project using GPU. I installed OpenCV v2.4.13 and NVidia CUDA Toolkit. I added additional include and library directories in configuration and OpenCV project works correctly without GPU functions. But when I'm trying to run openCV with GPU I get an error like this:

OpenCV Error: No GPU support (The library is compiled without CUDA support) in EmptyFuncTable::mallocPitch, file C:\builds\2_4_PackSlave_win32_vc12-shared\opencv\modules\dynamicuda\include\opencv2/dynamicuda/dynamicuda.hpp, line 126

Libary has been compiled without CUDA, so i tried to build the sources myself, with WITH_CUDA=ON in CMake, but when building Visual Studio 2013 has been giving me an errors that he cannot find opencv_core2413d.lib.

What can I do with this?

Comment: compile the debug build if you want the debug libraries (*d.lib)

Comment: I tried to compile the debug build and the Visual giving me 81 errors like "Cannot open input file opencv_core2413.lib"

Comment: during opencv building or after opencv building, trying to compile your ow code?

Comment: I'm doing nothing during opencv building, but compiler is working if you mean that.

Comment: from your question it isn't clear whether the error occurs during building openCV or whether building openCV did work and you get the error later when you try to compile/link your own project where you want to use openCV

Comment: With downloaded librarires from opencv.org error occurs when I'm trying to run simple app using opencv's gpu. So i have read that is beacause opencv has not been compiled with option WITH_CUDA = ON. When I'm trying to compile opencv myself, Visual Studio giving me errors like "Cannot find file opencv_core2413.lib and other opencv libs."

Comment: if you are using CMake Gui, please add a screenshot of your settings.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ffx0f7
http://prntscr.com/ffx0u4
http://prntscr.com/ffx0z6